# Custom Errormessage for Celledit Errors

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have created a new DataTable with some Numeric Columns and bound the data to a Datagridview

```
dtFCData.Columns.Add(iC.ToString, System.Type.GetType("System.Double"))
```

The Users of the Application can now edit values in this Column.
If they enter not numeric text and confirm it, the default Error Message is Displayed.
How can i replace this ugly Errormessage by my own message?
 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i have found it.
In the Datagridview is a DataError event.
Here can the DefaultError be replaced

[MSDN DataError Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)